# Probability over many games

Tags: probability

I'm working on Project Euler problem number 205 which states:

> Peter has nine four-sided (pyramidal)
>   dice, each with faces numbered 1, 2,
>   3, 4. Colin has six six-sided (cubic)
>   dice, each with faces numbered 1, 2,
>   3, 4, 5, 6.
>
> Peter and Colin roll their dice and
>   compare totals: the highest total
>   wins. The result is a draw if the
>   totals are equal.
>
> What is the probability that Pyramidal
>   Pete beats Cubic Colin? Give your
>   answer rounded to seven decimal places
>   in the form 0.abcdefg

My initial attempt (below) involved having 1,000 "games", where each game had 1,000,000 turns. Then taking the average of all the games. I'm consistently getting results in the .559 area, but when the answer needs to be to 7 decimal places, that's not that close.

```
public class pe205 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        pe205 p = new pe205();

        double sum = 0.0;

        for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++){
            sum += p.determineProbability();
        }

        System.out.println(sum/1000.0);

    } // end main

    public double determineProbability(){

        int peterWins = 0;
        int colinWins = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < 1000000; i++){

            int peterSum = 0;
            for(int j=0; j < 4; j++){
                Random r = new Random();
                peterSum += r.nextInt(9);
            }

            //System.out.println(peterSum);

            int colinSum = 0;
            for(int j=0; j < 6; j++){
                Random r = new Random();
                colinSum += r.nextInt(6);
            }

            //System.out.println(colinSum);

            if(peterSum > colinSum){
                peterWins++;
            }
            if(colinSum > peterSum){
                colinWins++;
            }

        }
        double peteBeatsColin = (double)peterWins/(double)(colinWins + peterWins);

        return peteBeatsColin;

    }

} // end class
```

I've read about the Monte Carlo method. Would this be a situation where that would be useful, and if so, could someone give me a brief walk through? Or is it that I'm missing some fairly obvious mathematical solution?

I would like to say that I enjoy the challenge of these problems, and I'm not looking for the answer, just a little push in the right direction.

Comment: It's typically not the case that Monte Carlo is a practical solution when so many decimal places are required. Think of the Buffon needle problem. It converges to pi, but very slowly (unless you happen to be  Mario Lazzarini).

Comment: Error convergence is square root [error ~ 1 / sqrt(N)] so you probably need O(10^12) test points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try to calculate the result combinatorially?  Explicitly calculate the result by adding terms of the form

```
a_i = P(peter throws i, Colin throws < i)
```

Comment: I dont want to give away too much as others may want to do it

Comment: Thank you for your insights! It was a combination of the top three answers that helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out. An exact solution is possible. Here's a nudge.

Peter can roll 9 to 36.

Colin can roll 6 to 36.

Calculate the probability that Peter can roll `r` where `r` ranges from 9 to 36.

Do the same for Colin, `r` ranging from 6 to 36.

From here you can calculate the probability that Peter beats Colin.

Comment: Thank you for the nudge! It was a combination of the top three answers that helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

First, write a function that calculates the probability of N S-sided dice resulting in a given value C.

Once you have that, write a function to add up the probability that a given set of dice will roll less than a certain number.

Once you have that, write a function that loops over `n->(n*s)` and calculates the probability that the other set of dice will be less than or equal to that.

Remember, the probability of A and B, if they are not entangled, is `P(A) * P(B)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It was a combination of the top three answers that helped me out.

Answer (score -1):

```
double colin(int n)
{
  int t = 0;
  for(int d1 = 1; d1<7; d1++)
  for(int d2 = 1; d2<7; d2++)
  for(int d3 = 1; d3<7; d3++)
  for(int d4 = 1; d4<7; d4++)
  for(int d5 = 1; d5<7; d5++)
  for(int d6 = 1; d6<7; d6++)
  if(d1+d2+d3+d4+d5+d6 == n)
  t++;
  return ((double)t)/(6*6*6*6*6*6);
}
```

-*** This is if peter has only 4 dice not nine, i got lazy ***

```
double peter(int n)
{
  int t = 0;
  for(int d1 = 1; d1<5; d1++)
  for(int d2 = 1; d2<5; d2++)
  for(int d3 = 1; d3<5; d3++)
  for(int d4 = 1; d4<5; d4++)
  if(d1+d2+d3+d4 == n)
  t++;
  return ((double)t)/(4*4*4*4);
}
main()
{
  double r = 0.0;
  for(int c = 4; c < 16; c++){
    for(int p = 6; p < 36; p++){
      if(c > p){
        r += colin(c)*peter(p);
      }
    }
  }
  System.out.println(r);
}
```

Please excuse the extreme inefficiency, but you get the point.

Comment: "I would like to say that I enjoy the challenge of these problems, and I'm not looking for the answer, just a little push in the right direction."

Comment: "if you are unable to solve a particular problem. If you can't solve it, then you can't solve it!"

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your input. I didn't look at your code until I had completed the problem, but it's nice to have a comparison to make sure I'm doing the work efficiently.